# Datepicker - change date format if selected date is 1st day of month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jQuery datepicker but I want to be able to change the format of the date depending on whether the date picked is the 1st day of the month.

I know I need to use `onSelect: function() { ... }` but I'm really not sure how to insert the if statement into here based on what has been selected to change the date format.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm curious -- why would you want to do this?

Comment: If I tell you I'll have to ki.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be something like:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    if( dateText.substring(0,2) == "01" ){  //first two characters of the string
        //change format
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can add a change listener containing the same code to your date element and do it that way: $( "#element" ).change(function() { });

Comment: Awesome except for the fact that I thought it would be as simple as putting `dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"` in the if statement... it would seem not though. The if statement is working (tested with alert) but the dateformat is not changing... any ideas?

Comment: `var origDate = new Date(dateText);`
Then you have to reformat it, for example:
`var newDate = new Date(origDate.getUTCFullYear(), origDate.getUTCMonth(), origDate.getUTCDate());`

Look up the date javascript object for more formatting functions.